# Problem reading from rest api with autogenerated BigInt Id

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, bigint, cockroachdb

I'm having some issues with my rest api when I try to read from database.
My server stack right now is NestJS + Prisma + Cockroachdb

At first when I generated a new User, with a POST, all went great and got it to go to my database.
[image: 1]
But when I tried to read from it it went really wrong and gave me an error, saying that couldn't serialize a BigInt.

I googled a lot and found a fix for it ('json-bigint-patch'), but now instead of getting an error it just returns me 'null'.
[image: 2]

Later I found out if I manually change the autogenerated ID for a smaller number, I get the result as I was expecting.
[image: 3]

So right now I'm stuck with this and I dont know how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help in advance

Note: I'm really new at all this

Comment: here is one potential approach: https://dev.to/jhatcher9999/cockroachdb-creating-limited-key-ranges-1dh5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.